# How does the specificity of a sentence change?

Tags: definite-article, generic-noun-phrases

[Source](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article)

> Joe plays the piano really well.
>
> Joe plays piano really well.

The former means *Joe can play any piano* while the latter one means *Joe can play only this piano*?

[Source](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=XKtsV67OJ-LA8geaipnwBQ#q=england)

> Paris is the capital of France.
>
> The capital, London, on the River Thames, is home of Parliament and the 11th-century Tower of London, but is also a multicultural, 21st-century hub for the arts and business in "The City."

*The capital* is correct while *the home* not.Why?

Comment: Related question: [Omitting article with musical instruments](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6635/48335)

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47110/a-capital-of-a-country-vs-the-capital-of-some-country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Joe plays **the piano** really well.
>
> Joe plays **piano** really well.

As said by Alan Carmac and as [explained in the answers to this question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6635/48335), neither of the two sentences implies a particular piano. If you want the linguistic term for this phenomenon, it is "generic noun phrase". Here [are questions on ELL about generic noun phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generic-noun-phrases).

In English, a noun can sometimes refer to a class of things or to a typical representative of a class even then there is an article ("the" or "a") before the noun.

According to some native speakers, the phrase without an article gives "[a slight feeling of playing with a group or orchestra](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6636/48335)" (I play the part devoted to the piano when I participate in orchestra performances), whereas using the article puts more focus on the instrument. But other native speakers disagree (see comments below).

The version with "the" might be more widespread:

[image]

If you're interested in generic phrases, Jown Lawler wrote a dissertation on them. [In this answer he provides some links](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93854/48335). Regarding "I play the piano", he says that "[In that sentence the whole verb phrase is generic, and the noun gets it from that. See Chapter II.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93834/usage-of-english-definite-article-when-referring-to-generic-word/93854#comment189786_93854)"

P.S. A related post on Language Log:

- [Metaphysical overlap and violin supervenience](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2020), by Geoffrey Pullum, 2010

Comment: What about 'the home and the capital'?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh -- oops. I thought someone else would answer that, and Alan Carmack answered it partly. Your question is really two questions. I'd say "London is home of Parliament" is a kind of idiomatic expression with the meaning "London is where (the country's) Parliament is located".

Comment: In and of itself, the absence of the article does not give "a slight feeling of playing with a group", despite that answer on ELU.  "She plays piano" does not at all imply or hint that she's in an orchestra. "He plays banjo" does not suggest that he's in a bluegrass band. She plays woodwinds, on the other hand, might imply it, but that is because the instrument has been identified by its type (*woodwinds* is a section of the orchestra).

Comment: @TRomano - that leaves me baffled, as a non-native speaker. Maybe "She plays piano" implies "a role in a group" only then it is part of a larger phrase like "She plays piano with the Munich Orchestra"? And when "She plays piano." is a standalone sentence, it implies exactly the same thing as "She plays the piano"?

Comment: "with the Munich Orchestra" is conveying that idea.  He eats bananas with the monkeys at the zoo.

Comment: **She plays piano**: she is a piano player; she knows how to make music on a (i.e. any) piano.    **She plays the piano** means the same, but has the capacity, when extended, to mean something specific: "She plays the piano her mother played as a child."

Comment: @TRomano - so I should vigorously dowvote and downcomment the answers over on ELU?

Comment: Yes, vigorously and indiscriminately.  :)

Comment: Remember, articles are also deictic in context. If you ask, "Where is your daughter?" and I say "She's playing the piano", I would be referring to a piano that I know to exist elsewhere, probably in another room of the house, and I would expect you, as listener, to understand that I am referring to her current activity and to a piano elsewhere in the house, even if you had never laid eyes on it.

Comment: But if you ask "What is your daughter up to these days? Is she still busking by the subway exit with her guitar?" and I reply "She's playing the piano", then I am not referring to a specific piano in my house, but to the instrument in generic terms.

Comment: In the piano-elsewhere-in-the-house example two above, the context might be you are a dinner guest. You are in the house.

Comment: I also do not agree with 'the phrase without an article gives "a slight feeling of playing with a group or orchestra" (I play the part devoted to the piano when I participate in orchestra performances), whereas using the article puts more focus on the instrument.' I agree with fumblefinger's [comment about it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6635/omission-of-definite-article-with-musical-instruments/6636#comment59824_6636).

Comment: Okay, I changed my answer a bit. Live and learn. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

*The piano* and *piano* are pretty much interchangeable and refer to the piano in general, not to any particular piano. If you want to refer to a specific piano, you would have to use *this piano* or *that piano*. Even when John is playing a piano, and you say *John plays the piano really well*, you are referring to a generic piano, not the one John is actually playing. This usage of *the* with (some?) instruments is an interesting facet of English.

You can omit *the* in the sentence about Paris, giving you

> Paris is capital of France.

This leads directly to your question about *home*. You can also use *the home* in the sentence you provided.

But you would not say

> *Capital, London, on the River Thames...

Rather than try to figure out rules, just accept the fact that English is not always consistent in its application of the definite article.

Comment: Can we really omit 'the' in "[city] is capital of [country]"? Ngram says that [the version with 'the' is way more widespread](https://goo.gl/PaUxqw).

Comment: My answer talks about a natural English construction; I'm not concerned with how widespread such usage may or may not be.

Comment: What about 'the home and the capital'?

Comment: I corroborate Alan's statement that "the" can be omitted in "Paris is capital of France" but searching through my database of anything anyone has ever said within earshot of me (I have a micro-USB port behind my left ear and download nightly), I would venture to say that the context of such a statement is likely to be question-and-answer: *What is the capital of France? -- Paris is capital of France.*  We would  not ask "*What is capital of France?" We might ask "What city is capital of France?" or "What's the capital of France?"

Comment: Well, *What is capital of France?* is just as grammatical. Offhand, I don't know why a simple *wh- question word* form would make the corresponding   statement  ungrammatical.

Comment: I asked a number of native speakers (though all were from Central Atlantic, US, like myself) and all said that they would not ask the question "What is capital of ....?"

Answer (score 0):

Quote:   'The capital, London, on the River Thames, is home of Parliament...'
'The capital is correct while the home not.Why?'
Quote ended.

Home with the meaning 'there where you live and feel best' can be meant as uncountable or countable:

I'm at home.  (uncountable)

He has 2 homes.  (countable)

Your excerpt has 'home' as uncountable and it's correct.